# writing to file implementation

Tags: c#, .net

I just want to learn something new here about my code.

I have the following function ,is it the optimized way to return if I had a problem during writing to a file? or there is a better way doing so..

```
public static bool WriteFile(ByteBuffer data  , String fileName, bool append)
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append);
            var errorVal = true;
            try
            {
                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                errorVal = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                writer.Dispose();
            }

            return errorVal;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some more specific exception type for more specific errors.

Comment: @Lobo I just need to know that i have an exception for false returning , not really dealing with them.

Comment: In this case, if you just need to have a Boolean result, well done I see the function. But it is always best to know what kind of exception and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* want to eat all exceptions and just return a `bool`, I would rather do it like this:

```
public static bool WriteFile(ByteBuffer data, String fileName, bool append)
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append))
    {
        try
        {
            writer.Write(data);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log the exception details; don't just eat it.
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That said, if it was my own code, I would probably not catch the exception at all in here, but rather leave that up to the calling code:

```
public static void WriteFile(ByteBuffer data, String fileName, bool append)
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append))
    {
        writer.Write(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to let it throw the exception to a top layer in your layer architecture of the application.

```
public static void WriteFile(ByteBuffer data  , String fileName, bool append) throws Exception
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append);

                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();

                writer.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should always use `using(...)` for each object implementing `IDisposable` interface, so you can be sure it will be disposed when it goes out of scope.

```
public static bool WriteFile(ByteBuffer data, String fileName, bool append)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append))
    {
         try
         {
              writer.Write(data);
              writer.Flush();
              return true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex) 
         { 
             // Do domething here, maybe log ex.Message
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest remove code

```
Exception ex
```

from catch section

Comment: Why that? To catch even more (unwanted) or state corrupting (in .NET prior to 4.0 at least) exceptions?

Comment: Yup, but he should. And also there is a significant difference between `catch` and `catch (Exception)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what others have said, about handling exceptions at a higher level and let them just bubble up.

If you really "must" handle them here and just return true or false, note that all the other solutions so far, fail to catch the exception that might happen when opening/creating the file.

Also note, that I would still go through the hassle of only catching those exceptions that actually are being documented as those that could happen.

To do so, you need to put the `StreamWriter` constructor in the `try` block as well:

```
public static bool WriteFile(ByteBuffer data, string fileName, bool append)
{
  StreamWriter writer = null;
  Exception exception = null;

  try
  {
     writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, append);
     writer.Write(data);
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  {
     exception = ex;
  }
  catch (SecurityException ex)
  {
     exception = ex;
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
     exception = ex;
  }
  finally
  {
     if (writer != null)
     {
        try {
           writer.Close();
        } catch (EncoderFallbackException) { /* arguably log this as well */ }
     }

     if (exception != null)
     {
        // Log exception
        return false;
     }

     return true;
  }
}
```

Note that their are a couple of other ways to achieve the same behavior; including using `using` blocks or note caching the exception and logging it in `finally`, but directly in the respective `catch` blocks. YMMV.